# Core data issues with refactoring an entity

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, core-data-migration

We have an entity called "EMail" with attributes such as ID, From, To, Subject, Body.

Due to various reasons including performance for retrieval, impact on migration etc, we want to refactor this entity into two entities with a parent child relationship:
"EMail": ID, From, To, Subject and "EMailBody": ID, Body.

Can this be done with an existing model? If so, will this still fall under lightweight migration?

Comment: May I ask why you don't try searching 'core data divide entity' and help yourself, first?

Comment: No, you can't do that with lightweight migration. Apple provides a [detailed list](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html) of every change possible with lightweight migration, and this is not one of them.

Comment: @TomHarrington can we achieve lightweight migration by introducing new child entity as "EMailBody" and leave the "EMail" as parent. We made a setup like this, there was no error and light weight migration happened for introducing the new entity but "EMailBody" is simply empty. When we try heavy weight migration due to big Body size, our app is terminated by the operating system.

Comment: You can do that, and you’ve already seen what the result is. If that’s what you want, go ahead, but you can’t make the changes your question describes with lightweight migration.